# Widget Simulator does not display elements of "Today Extension”

Tags: osx-yosemite

I want to implement the “Today Extension” feature into one of my applications. I successfully added the extension, gave it a run and saw the “Hello World” screen on the simulator. I then deleted the "Hello World” label, and added my own labels to the view. Nothing spectacular and really nothing I thought which would make me any trouble…

Now when I run the widget all I get is an empty Simulator:

[image: Empty Simulator]

Things I tried:

- Checked that "File’s Owner" has the view connected
- Coloured the labels and made sure they aren’t hidden
- Checked if the view’s controller gets initialised accordingly
- Fiddled around with Autolayout: The extension view does look like a (too) small bar compared to the size I assigned. The strange thing is, that even if I drag one label to the top, it does not appear
- Tried a “Clean” and “Clean Build Folder” and also “Clear Snapshot” in the simulator
- Downloaded a [working today extension](https://github.com/janniklorenz/TodayTimer) from Github to check if I did something wrong. Couldn’t find anything.

It does seem like I’m working on the wrong view. But it is in fact the same view which displayed me the “Hello Word” label. Am I missing something? (@Moderator: I suggest adding the following tags: osx-today-widget, widget-simulator. Thanks in advance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the code it is hard to say, but maybe this helps:

what text color does your label have?
make sure to give it "**Control text color**"

what is your minimum height>
click the "Custom view" in your xib file (the root view) and click Editor > Pin > Height.
Set it to 200 and "greater or equal than"

Comment: I gave them all a red color to be sure I will see them. I also changed the Height to 500 to make sure I will see it. It still does not work.

Comment: Try changing the color to what I suggested. I remember that I couldn't see my text as well and thought it didn't work

Comment: Also try setting your contentHeight manually in widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler

Comment: Pinning the height actually solved my problem. I’m sorry when I did sound ignorant on my first comment. I was fairly sure setting it to 500px manually would to the job. Thanks for your suggestion!